# Display text in textbox when clicked in OK message

Tags: c#, textbox

I am trying to develop a program to show a message "PASS" (inside the textBox2) when the 2 conditions happen:

1) When the textBox1 receives a text containing "1" in the first string

and

2) When the "ENTER" key is pressed to send the text contained in (this text will be send to SQL db)

It is very difficult to me to develop a if function to insert these two conditions. Any help will be appreciated, thank you so much.

Below is a piece of code I´ve tried:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      string input = textBox2.Text;
      string strName = "PASS";


      if (input.StartsWith("G") && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Enter) != 0)

      {
          textBox5.Text = strName;
          //CHANGE_COLOR = green
      }
}
```

Comment: can you attach the code that have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

**1st condition:** You may use **KeyPressEventArgs** to determine which key has been pressed.

**2nd condition:** You may choose to implement a seperate function that will check whether or not there is a '1' character in the first string of **textBox1**.

**Goal:** If both conditions occur, **textBox2**'s text will be: "PASS".

I offer the following solution:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char _enter = (char)13;
        if (e.KeyChar == _enter && isFirstStringContaining1())
            textBox2.Text = "PASS";
        else
            textBox2.Text = "";
    }

    private bool isFirstStringContaining1()
    {
        int length = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(' ');
        if (length == -1)
            length = textBox1.Text.Length;
        string first_str = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, length);
        foreach (char c in first_str)
            if (c.Equals('1'))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You give no details for me to help you .. What in it didn't work? It works perfectly, I just ran it. Did you just copy-paste it? If yes, you shouldn't have .. You should specify relevant events for each control at the Properties -> Events. (Thunder Icon), there you should write the name of the function that will be triggered by the event. You should as well adjust the code to your own 'controls names' (For example, I've seen that at your case, it isn't textBox1 and textBox2, but textBox2 and textBox5 ..